# Read from json file into IEnumerable using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, type-conversion, system.text.json

I've a problem by reading from a json to a IEnumerable in C# with System.Text.Json...

That's the error:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String[]]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
```

The following lines contain my code:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string[]>? GetStaticMedicalAdvisors()
{
    // TODO - read from json
    // TODO - convert to contact
    // TODO - add contacts to list
    // TODO - DO NOT USE NEWTONSOFT.JSON (use System.Text.Json)
    // TODO - return list

    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MedicalAdvisors.json");
    var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, String[]>>(json);

    return dict;
}
```

This is my `MedicalAdvisors.json`:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Franz Immer",
    "endpoint": "000",
    "country": "CH"
  },
  {
    "name": "Nathalie Krügel",
    "endpoint": "000",
    "country": "CH"
  }
]
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see a small sample of MedicalAdvisors.json too.

Comment: This what the json representation of a dictionary<string, string[]> looks like. Does the data in your file follow this pattern? `{"key1":["a","b","c"],"key2":["d","e","f"],"key3":["g","h","i"]}`

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes it looks like that have a look into my json file I added it to my question a moment ago.

Comment: No, it does not look the same. You have an array of items, not a dictionary.

Comment: @Crowcoder yeah you're right, my bad.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string[]>`? So you're expecting each json property to contain a string *array*? But your example json only has string values. Not arrays of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json will deserialize as:
`var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>[]>(json);`

However, wouldn't it be more useful to create a Type that matches the structure?

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string endpoint { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserInfo[]>(json);
```

Comment: Yeah I already have a class exactly like that.

Comment: But now i will get an empty string in swagger....

Comment: Your question lacks the context to know what Swagger has to do with it.

Comment: ah i fixed it thanks a lot for the hint with the userinfo i will accept your question probably you can upvote the entire question because there aren't much tutorials on the internet.